# Github Pages React App Blank Page & Returning 404

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I've been looking at many forums for a solution but haven't found any. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using react and styled components to create a website on GitHub Pages, but i keep getting a blank page and a 404 error in the console which is:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

"main.79bf5a2e.js"

My repository: https://github.com/Visibyte/Space-Tourism

My package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "https://visibyte.github.io/space-tourism",
  "name": "space-tourism-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?